# Using Xcode reopen project, project runs fine

Tags: ios, xcode

I have some code like this

```
[self setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES]; 
[navController pushViewController:calendarListVC animated:NO]; 
[self setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:NO];
```

First, I can't get the result what I want. I think there may be some problem with my code. But I reopen this project by accident. And the problem all gone. The result what I expect showed. I want to know why this weird thing happen. Do any one know it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problems and the easiest solution I found was doing `Clean Build` (by pressing Command+Shift+K keys) before building

Comment: But it's waste time too much.